# VisualStudio Online TestAgent behind proxy

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure-devops

summary:

I'm having difficulties getting the test agent to deploy as part of the build process in Visual Studio Online for a website, maybe due to network proxy.

details:

I work for Crab Company, "cc" for short (no, not really), and we have an account at https://cc.visualstudio.com .

We have an on-premise build server, "ccvsts", Windows Server 2012 R2.

We have an instance that will be used for intranet testing and will be hosting the website, "ccwebt1", Windows Server 2016.

Network traffic is filtered. Ports were opened. Intranet machines connect to the internet using a proxy.

We have some tests for the website utilizing Selenium. I'm trying to incorporate this testing following the guide at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-selenium but instead of building the solution (which has a bunch of projects) I've got it building just the website project and test project:

[image: build steps]

I've gotten to the point where the project builds, and past some initial networking issues, but I think now I'm running into a problem due to the proxy. I *think* the relevant exception is

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 104.214.111.103:443

Note that cc.visualstudio.com resolves to 104.214.111.103
Also note, this is failing on the "Deploy TestAgent on" build step.
Also also note, the first build steps do succeed and code is generated on ccvsts, so the build agent (at least) can already communicate with Visual Studio Online.

I believe this is proxy related by example of the following powershell

```
PS > $R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://www.bing.com?q=how+many+feet+in+a+mile
Invoke-WebRequest :
Access Denied (authentication_failed)
Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your
credentials can be verified.
```

However, this might be a credential issue. The requirements for the test agent were a bit unclear to me, so I have set up a *local* user account and *local* admin account on ccwebt1, but neither account has access to VSTS. I don't know if this will cause problems or not.

---

To summarize my question

1) If the network proxy is preventing access to visual studio online in the test agent power shell script, how can I fix that?

2) Will using *local* accounts for the test agent prevent access to visual studio online?

---

Log below (with a few values renamed, but otherwise unmodified)

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Deploy TestAgent on
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
Description  : Deploy and configure Test Agent to run tests on a set of machines
Version      : 2.1.20
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=838890)
==============================================================================
****************************************************************
                    Task Input Information                      
----------------------------------------------------------------
testMachineInput         = ccwebt1
adminUserName            = ccwebt1\ccwebt1localadmin
winRmProtocal            = Http
testCertificate          = true
machineUserName          = ccwebt1\ccwebt1local
runAsProcess             = false
logonAutomatically       = false
disableScreenSaver       = false
isDataCollectionOnly     = false
testPlatform             = 14.0
agentLocation            = 
updateTestAgent          = false
****************************************************************
Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.
Inputs provided are:
Use HTTP Port: True
Username: ccwebt1\ccwebt1local
Disable Screen saver: False
Login Automatically: False
Run as process: False
Agent would be downloaded from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472
Update test agent: False
Run test agent as DataCollection only : False
Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' is being run
     Deployment started on target machine...
Query for Testplatfrom version: 14.0
Test Agent does not exists
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 2 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:37:45:2421; 4784, 4](ccwebt1)Created public key for communication
RemoteDeployerSource Information: 12 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:37:45:2576; 4784, 4](ccwebt1)Deployment service - VisualStudioRemoteDeployer553ef14b-0634-460a-b535-cb40cbcb2409 is running...
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 4 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:37:46:2851; 4784, 6](ccwebt1)Input file found
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 5 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:37:46:2851; 4784, 6](ccwebt1)Reading input parameters
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 6 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:37:46:2851; 4784, 6](ccwebt1)Finished reading input parameters
Task 'VerifyTestAgentInstalled' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' completed.
Starting to download testagent
Test agent download is taking time. Please wait.
testagent is downloaded at: C:\TestAgent\365dea8f-557e-45e8-bb1d-fa59563f01ef
Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' is being run
\\ccwebt1 was deleted successfully.
Copying recursively from C:\TestAgent\365dea8f-557e-45e8-bb1d-fa59563f01ef to C:\TestAgent on machine ccwebt1 succeeded.
\\ccwebt1 was deleted successfully.
Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' completed.
Task 'InstallTestAgent' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' is being run
Task 'InstallTestAgent' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
Task 'InstallTestAgent' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' completed.
     Deployment started on target machine...
Setup path: C:\TestAgent\vstf_testagent.exe
Installed Test Agent version: 0.0
Requested Test Agent version: 14.0.25463
Test Agent will be installed
Invoking the command C:\TestAgent\vstf_testagent.exe with arguments 
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 2 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:39:18:4378; 420, 4](ccwebt1)Created public key for communication
RemoteDeployerSource Information: 12 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:39:18:4534; 420, 4](ccwebt1)Deployment service - VisualStudioRemoteDeployer3c6e52bc-5767-4bfd-9dba-f056c5d90671 is running...
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 4 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:39:19:4789; 420, 6](ccwebt1)Input file found
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 5 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:39:19:4789; 420, 6](ccwebt1)Reading input parameters
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 6 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:39:19:4945; 420, 6](ccwebt1)Finished reading input parameters
Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' is being run
Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' completed.
\\ccwebt1 was deleted successfully.
Copying recursively from C:\agent\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\2.1.20\TestExecution.zip to C:\TestAgent on machine ccwebt1 succeeded.
\\ccwebt1 was deleted successfully.
Task 'TestAgentConfiguration' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' is being run
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 2 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:40:28:2919; 3220, 4](ccwebt1)Created public key for communication
RemoteDeployerSource Information: 12 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:40:28:2919; 3220, 4](ccwebt1)Deployment service - VisualStudioRemoteDeployer1b3bbb26-a295-47a6-93bb-1432b9140099 is running...
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 4 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:40:29:3232; 3220, 6](ccwebt1)Input file found
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 5 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:40:29:3232; 3220, 6](ccwebt1)Reading input parameters
RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 6 : [RemoteDeployer][12:Sep:17:11:40:29:3232; 3220, 6](ccwebt1)Finished reading input parameters
Task 'TestAgentConfiguration' on machine 'ccwebt1:5985' completed.
Task 'TestAgentConfiguration' for machine ccwebt1:5985's Error : System.Exception: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server
Task 'TestAgentConfiguration' for machine ccwebt1:5985's Log :
     Deployment started on target machine...
System.AggregateException: Failed to execute the powershell script. Consult the logs below for details of the error.
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server ---> System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<Invoke>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute[T](Func`1 action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.ScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(IPowerShell powerShell, String script, String arguments, Boolean isScriptDotSourced, Boolean useHttp)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.DeploymentService.RunPowerShellScripts(DeploymentMachineSpecification deploymentMachine, ScriptSpecification scriptSpecification, ScriptSpecification initializationScriptSpecification, String applicationPath, IPowerShell powerShellSession)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<Invoke>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute[T](Func`1 action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)<---
Test User ccwebt1local
Test UserDomain ccwebt1
Path: C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'.
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.TestExecution.dll'.
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll'.
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.dll'.
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll'.
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\TfsAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll'.
Loading module from path 'C:\TestAgent\PrivateAssemblies\MS.VS.TestService.Client.Utility.dll'.
****************************************************************
                    Configure Test Agent                      
----------------------------------------------------------------
SetupPath                       : (C:\TestAgent)
TestUserName                    : (ccwebt1\ccwebt1local)
TfsCollection                   : (https://cc.visualstudio.com/)
AsServiceOrProcess              : (Service)
EnvironmentUrl                  : (dta://env/2d109582-6dad-402e-8297-aa8de2398194/_apis//201709121137404659)
MachineName                     : (ccwebt1)
Capabilities                    : ()
TestAgentVersion                : (14.0)
****************************************************************
Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server, Check if TFS is reachable from the test agent. Exception Details : 
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 104.214.111.103:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\Common\VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.cs:line 159
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__48.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 818
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__45`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssHttpClientBase.cs:line 721
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\HttpClients\LocationHttpClient.cs:line 71
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\Location\ServerDataProvider.cs:line 692
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<EnsureConnectedAsync>d__39.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\Location\ServerDataProvider.cs:line 642
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<GetInstanceIdAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\Location\ServerDataProvider.cs:line 174
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.<GetLocationDataAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\Location\LocationService.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.<GetClientInstanceAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssConnection.cs:line 357
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.<GetClientServiceImplAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssConnection.cs:line 299
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.<GetClientAsync>d__12`1.MoveNext() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssConnection.cs:line 227
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task) in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\TaskExtensions.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]() in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\VssConnection.cs:line 195
   at MS.VS.TestService.Client.Utility.TestExecutionServiceRestApiHelper.Initialize(String serviceUrl, String accesToken) in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Ta\Agent\VS.TestService.Client.Utility\RestApiHelper.cs:line 108
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MS.VS.TestService.Client.Utility.TestExecutionServiceRestApiHelper.RunTaskWithRetriesOnServiceUnavailability[T](Func`1 getTask) in E:\v2.0\A5\_work\1\s\Ta\Agent\VS.TestService.Client.Utility\RestApiHelper.cs:line 158
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryConstructorInvoke(MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] arguments, Object[] originalArguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.ConstructorInvokeDotNet(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand.CallConstructor(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] args)
Error occurred on 'ccwebt1:5985'. Details : 'The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server'. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Deploy TestAgent on
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Also, if someone can tell me how to invoke `Get-VstsEndpoint` so I can debug this issue that would be helpful

Comment: Try to add VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME (proxyuser) and VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD (proxypassword) environment variables to ccwebt1 machine.

Comment: Hi @BurnsBA, I don't think it's your proxy. Reason 1) your on-premise build agent is able to communicate with cc.visualstudio.com. Reason 2) the failure is happening during the "Deploy Test Agent..." task. Instead, I think that the issue is your connection to your test server. In particular, I think you should confirm that you can remote powershell from your build server to your test server.